# Pendrive not detected in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: usb-drive

My sandisk pendrive when plugged in turns up in disk utility application but is not detected in ubuntu home.I used this pendrive to install ubuntu in my computer.After that,it is not detected by ubuntu.In windows it is detected as a pendrive with 0 capacity.Please help me.
The output of `lsblk`  is

```
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda       8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1    8:1    0   260M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2    8:2    0   128M  0 part 
├─sda3    8:3    0  82.1G  0 part 
├─sda4    8:4    0 205.7G  0 part 
├─sda5    8:5    0 205.7G  0 part 
├─sda6    8:6    0   731M  0 part 
├─sda7    8:7    0  25.8G  0 part 
├─sda8    8:8    0   250G  0 part /media/renjith/0F871820666D9306
├─sda9    8:9    0  23.9G  0 part /
├─sda10   8:10   0   3.8G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda11   8:11   0 133.6G  0 part /home
sdb       8:16   1  28.7G  0 disk 
sr0      11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Comment: Connect that pendrive, do to terminal and execute `lsblk` , do you see the pendrive ? please paste that output

Comment: From the disk utility, you can format it, which will make it usable again.

Comment: `sdb       8:16   1  28.7G  0 disk` this is your pendrive